# how to compare time values in android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, datetimepicker

i am having the set of times in database and i want to compare with current time in computer .how it be done pls help me!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`Date.before()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before%28java.util.Date%29) or [`Date.compareTo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29) methods:

```
Date now = new Date();
Date date = ... //obtain it from db here
if (now.before(date)) {
  Log.d("date is in the future");
}
```